# How to return an object in a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

[My Local class is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gv5B.jpg)

I have this class on my program where I store the pointes of objects that I'm creating in this vector called **insumos**.

My problem is, how do I return a specific pointer of an object of this vector on a method that looks like this.

[Methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTSm9.jpg)

On the first method I'm able to return the vector, but how do I return lest say the first pointer of an object of the vector.

i have tried things like

```
Insumo *Local::getIn()
{
    return insumos.begin();
}
```

and didnt work

Comment: At stackoverflow we don't want pictures of code. Related: [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I'll remember that thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a subscript:

```
Insumo *Local::getIn()
{
    return insumos[0];
}
```

Subscript `0` means element #1, `1` means element #2, etc.

You can also do this:

```
Insumo *Local::getIn()
{
    return insumos.at(0);
}
```

which is equivalent to the first use case.

`begin()` returns an `iterator`, which is a more advanced topic.

More info on vectors: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector.

Comment: como boto como pergunta respondida?

Comment: Clique na marca de verificação